# What is full-entropy bit-strings?

Tags: randomness, pseudorandomness, pseudorandom-generators, shannon-entropy

I was going through the description of [NIST Randomness Beacon](http://www.nist.gov/itl/csd/ct/nist_beacon.cfm). I would like to know the meaning of the term

> full-entropy bit-strings

used in the third paragraph.

Comment: sequences of bits whose [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-entropy#Min-entropy) is equal to their length $\;$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The meaning is a bit string $x$ which is distributed uniformly on $\{0,1\}^{|x|}$.